# What does the word "it" refer to?

Tags: meaning

> The best way to eliminate all suffering in the world would be to
> eliminate all sentient life. If there were no living things capable of
> feeling pain, then there would be no pain. If it were possible to do
> this in a painless way, perhaps by means of a huge atomic explosion,
> then, by the principle of negative utilitarianism, this would be the
> morally right action. Even if a certain amount of pain were involved
> in the process, the long-term benefits in pain elimination would
> probably outweigh it. Yet this conclusion is hardly acceptable. At the
> very least negative utilitarianism needs to be reformulated so as to
> avoid **it**.

Philosophy: The basics

What does the word "it" refer to? **a certain amount of pain** or **this conclusion**?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If asking about the penultimate "it", the reference is "this conclusion". Negative utilitarianism needs to not lead to the elimination of all life being the correct answer.

Comment: Oh, I thought that the penultimate "it" refers to a certain amount of pain

Comment: The last "it" refers to "this conclusion". The whole point of this essay is this: if this philosophy leads to concluding that destroying all life is the answer, we must reformulate the philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

> Even if *a certain amount of pain* were involved in the process, the long-term benefits in pain elimination would probably outweigh it. Yet *this conclusion* is hardly acceptable. At the very least negative utilitarianism needs to be reformulated so as to avoid **it**.

A pronoun generally refers to the noun *most immediately* preceding it. In this case the **it** refers to **this conclusion**.

Comment: The "it" at the end of the first sentence refers to"a certain amount of pain."

Answer (score 0):

*it* refers to the state of having to choose between *suffering* and the unacceptable option of *eliminating it with a huge atomic explosion*.

Further, *this conclusion* refers to inflicting *a certain amount of pain* for the long-term benefits of pain elimination.